# Роль пространства имён Net platform Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, документация, .net-6

В принципе я ориентируюсь на windows разработку. Не получается найти официальное позиционирование по этим пространствам имён. Всё что я смог извлечь из поиска,так это то, что они каким то образом взаимосвязаны с Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility. Как я понимаю вышеописанное пространствовать имён нужно для использования API, которые остались не перенесёнными в .NET, что я предполагаю является атрибутами windows API, и следовательно не могут быть развернуты в средах отличных от windows. Собственно вопрос заключается в следующим,соответствует ли моё утверждение выше по отношению к этим пространствам имён Microsoft.Extensions. Или они представляют иную логику? Прошу прояснить ситуацию по ним. Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как я понимаю, это вообще все [современное api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1). Но поскольку новый дотнет он ориентирован на кросс, то в него не включены исключительно виндовые вещи (например, PerformanceCounter) - вот их и положили в Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

Comment: Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility , точно позволяет использовать API из net framework. такие как WCF например. Возможно там и современные API присутствуют.  Меня смущает ответ из с английского стека https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097067/what-are-net-platform-extensions-on-docs-microsoft-com . Он какой то неполноценный. Честно говоря я его не понял. Суть в том что я сам что ли должен идентифицировать каждый из них, и поверять является ли он кросплатформенным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотеки из набора `Microsoft.Extensions` - это библиотеки от Microsoft, которые изначально не были частью стандартной библиотеки .NET Core, но предназначены для решений стандартных задач, возникающих при написании современных программ. В основном эти библиотеки создавались как составные части для построение ASP.NET Core, однако они не считаются частью ASP.NET Core потому что могут применяться не только для веб-приложений.

К примеру, пакеты из серии Logging можно использовать для ведения логов так же как их ведут приложения на ASP.NET Core, Configuration предоставляет возможность работать с файлами конфигурации в стиле appsettings.json - а DependencyInjection позволяет использовать DI в любом проекте.

К `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` эти пакеты не имеют никакого отношения, более того - они в некотором смысле противоположны: `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` предоставляет доступ к устаревшему API, а `Microsoft.Extensions` образуют новый API.

Comment: В принципе это правильный ответ. Я как раз читал что это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156484/how-exactly-does-microsoft-extensions-configuration-dependent-on-asp-net-core . Просто меня ввел в заблуждение ответ с английского стека. И отсутствие описания предназначения в  документации https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 . Я правильно понимаю что они тесно связанны с ASP.NET Core и Информацию по Configuration нужно искать в их контексте?

Comment: @ViktorVovnenko информацию по этим пакетам, скорее всего, проще найти в рамках статей по ASP.NET Core. Но прямой связи нет, пакеты называются Microsoft.Extensions а не Aspnetcore.Extensions не просто так.